# How they are shifting cover to non-cover space?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

I was reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.12806.pdf).

I am unable to understand the blocked step. Can anybody help me understanding that step?

Proof of Theorem 4. Define $\mathcal{W}_L \subseteq \mathcal{W}$ by
$$
\mathcal{W}_L \equiv\left\{\boldsymbol{w} \in \mathcal{W}: \operatorname{Lip}\left(f_{\boldsymbol{w}}\right) \leq L\right\}
$$
Denote $\mathcal{W}_{L, \epsilon} \subseteq \mathcal{W}_L$ for an $\frac{\epsilon}{8 J}$-net of $\mathcal{W}_L$. We have in particular $\left|\mathcal{W}_\epsilon\right| \leq\left(1+60 W \epsilon^{-1}\right)^p$ (see e.g. [Ver18, Corollary 4.2.13]). We apply Theorem 3 to $\mathcal{F}_{L, \epsilon} \equiv\left\{f_{\boldsymbol{w}}, \boldsymbol{w} \in \mathcal{W}_{L, \epsilon}\right\}$ :
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}_{L, \epsilon}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i-f\left(x_i\right)\right)^2 \leq \sigma^2-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) \\
& \leq(4 k+1) \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^2}{9^4 k}\right)+\exp \left(p \log \left(1+60 W J \epsilon^{-1}\right)-\Omega\left(\frac{\epsilon^2 n d}{c L^2 \sigma^2}\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

### Observe that if $\|f-g\|_{\infty} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{8}$ and $\|y\|_{\infty},\|f\|_{\infty},\|g\|_{\infty} \leq 1$, then
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i-f\left(x_i\right)\right)^2 \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i-g\left(x_i\right)\right)^2 .
$$

(We may again assume without loss of generality that all functions in $\mathcal{F}$ map to $[-1,1]$.) Thus we obtain for any $L>0$ and an absolute constant $C_1$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbb{P}\left(\exists f \in \mathcal{F}: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i-f\left(x_i\right)\right)^2 \leq \sigma^2-\epsilon \text { and } \operatorname{Lip}(f) \leq L\right) \\
& \leq(4 k+1) \exp \left(-\frac{n \epsilon^2}{10^4 k}\right)+\exp \left(p \log \left(1+60 W J \epsilon^{-1}\right)-\frac{\epsilon^2 n d}{C_1 c L^2 \sigma^2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

**My attempt**

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i-g\left(x_i\right)+g\left(x_i\right)-f\left(x_i\right)\right)^2\\
=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\left(y_i-g\left(x_i\right)\right)^2+2\left(y_i-g\left(x_i\right)\right)\left(g\left(x_i\right)-f\left(x_i\right)\right)+\left(g\left(x_i\right)-f\left(x_i\right)\right)^2\right)\\
\leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\left(y_i-g\left(x_i\right)\right)^2+2\cdot 1 \frac{\epsilon}{8}+ \frac{\epsilon^{2}}{64}\right)\\
\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i-g\left(x_i\right)\right)^2 
\end{equation}

$\left|y_i-g\left(x_i\right)\right|=\left|y_i\right|-\left|g\left(x_i\right)\right| \leq\left|y_i\right|+\left|g\left(x_i\right)\right| \leq 1+1=2$
So, $\left|y_i-g\left(x_i\right)\right| \leq 1$ and it was given in the paper

1. The function class can be written as $\mathcal{F}=\left\{f_{\boldsymbol{w}}, \boldsymbol{w} \in \mathcal{W}\right\}$ with $\mathcal{W} \subset \mathbb{R}^p$, $\operatorname{diam}(\mathcal{W}) \leq W$ and for any $\boldsymbol{w}_1, \boldsymbol{w}_2 \in \mathcal{W}$,
   $$
   \left\|f_{\boldsymbol{w}_1}-f_{\boldsymbol{w}_2}\right\|_{\infty} \leq J\left\|\boldsymbol{w}_1-\boldsymbol{w}_2\right\| .
   $$

---

**Can one verify this proof kindly!**